# Limiting zip file size

Tags: vbscript, zip

I have a script in VBScript that gets the content of a folder and gets it into a zip. It is mainly based on what I found in another post, as I am no VBS expert. This is the function:

```
Sub ArchiveFolder (zipFile, sFolder)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
        sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

        With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
            .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere .NameSpace(sFolder).Items

        Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = _
                 .NameSpace(sFolder).Items.Count
            WScript.Sleep 1000 
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

I need to divide the resulting file in size limited files (80MB). Is there a way to do this?

As I understand it, the `Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))` part is indicating to create a zip file, but I am not able to find an explanation of what this means and how to parametrize the action.

Comment: The byte sequence created by the instruction `Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))` or `"PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))` is the header of a zip file. Basically, creating a new "text" file with just these characters in it is the manual way of creating a new, empty zip file. There's nothing to parameterize about it. It also has nothing to do with the maximum size of the archive.

Comment: Understood. Not what i was thinking- Is there any other way of generating a fixed size zip file collection? The next step in the process has a size limit so I can't process the big ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved  it by using 7zip's portable version. There I can create the zip file with the parameters I need:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCmd = "7-Zip\7z.exe a -v80m " & zipFile & " " & sFolder 
oShell.Run(strCmd)
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to limiting the size of a zip file is to continue adding files until the maximum size is exceeded, then remove the last item added.

```
Sub ArchiveFolder (zipFile, sFolder)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        zipFile = .GetAbsolutePathName(zipFile)
        sFolder = .GetAbsolutePathName(sFolder)

        With .CreateTextFile(zipFile, True)
            .Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, chr(0))
        End With

        Set oZip = .GetFile(zipFile)
    End With

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        cnt = 0
        For Each currentItem In .NameSpace(sFolder).Items
            cnt = cnt + 1
            .NameSpace(zipFile).CopyHere currentItem

            Do Until .NameSpace(zipFile).Items.Count = cnt
                WScript.Sleep 1000
            Loop

            If oZip.Size > 83886080 Then
                Set lastItem = .NameSpace(zipFile).ParseName(f.Name)
                .NameSpace("C:\temp").MoveHere lastItem
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Of course there are more intelligent strategies than this to optimize space usage, but exploring them would be far too broad for an answer here.